# React Router useHistory go function not working properly

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-hooks, react-router-dom, mobx-react

I have a Typescript app and am using react-router-dom 5.1.2 and Mobx. It uses the useHistory hook. I have code that handles a form submission in a modal and then does a go(0) to go back to the prior page. The problem is that it seems to change the URL in the browser and does indeed go to that prior component, but the useEffect(...,[]) on that prior component is not called. I want to have my app go to that react component and ALWAYS call what is inside that component's useEffect hook. In other words I want to make sure that the component always reloads. How do i do that?

EDIT:
Here is the component that calls go(0) to go back.

```
export const MyComponent: React.FC<SomeProps> = observer(({
  onClick,
  id,
  onComplete,
  labels,
}: SomeProps) => {
  const { push, go } = useHistory();

  ...
  onSubmit=() => {
      ...
      go(0);
  }
}
```

And here is te component I want it to go back to. This component uses useEffect which does not get called when we go back.

```
export const MyBackContainer: React.FC = observer(() => {
  useEffect(() => {
    async function loadStuff() {
      await dataStore.loadStuff();
    }
    loadStuff();
  }, []);

  ...
```

}

Comment: Please share the relevant parts of code with us. Also see [How to create a Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: `go(-1)` is the equivalent of `goBack()`, `go(0)` shouldn't navigate anywhere.